# Strange Output while printing a char pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, while-loop

at the moment, I'm trying some pointer stuff in C. But now, I have a problem with a pointer array. By using my code below, I get a strange output. I think there is a big mistake in the code, but I can't find it.

I just want to print the strings of the pointer array.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *words[] = {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
    char *ptr;
    int i = 0;

    ptr = words[0];

    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        printf("%s", *(words+i));
        ptr++;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** word1word2word3Hã}¯HÉˇ

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you think this is doing `printf("%s", *(words+i));` ? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I think *(words) gives me the first value of my array. So I'm trying to go from index 0 to index 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(*ptr != '\0')
{
    printf("%s", *(words+i));
    ptr++;
    i++;
}
```

initially, `ptr` points to the `'w'` in `"word1"`. So the loop iterates five times until `*ptr == '\0'`. But the array `words` contains only three elements, thus the fourth and fifth iteration invoke undefined behaviour and garbage is printed when the bytes after the `words` array are interpreted as pointers to 0-terminated strings. It could easily crash, and if you try it on other systems, with other compilers or compiler settings, it will sometimes crash.

You could translate the loop to

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(words[0]); ++i) {
    printf("%s", words[i]);
}
```

to see more easily what it does.

If you want to print out the strings in the `words` array, you can use

```
// this only worls because words is an actual array, not a pointer
int numElems = sizeof words / sizeof words[0];
for(i = 0; i < numElems; ++i) {
    printf("%s", words[i]);
}
```

As `words` is an actual array, you can obtain the number of elements it contains using `sizeof`. Then you loop as many times as the array has elements.

Comment: You sure about the condition in the `for`? Wouldn't that iterate 5 times?

Comment: allright, I get your point. Thanks. But how could I solve it. I'm a little helpless :-/.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes, five times, that's how many non-zero `char`s there are in `"word1"`.

Comment: But for each iteration, you print `words[i]`... So the last iteration, you call `printf("%s", words[4]);`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's a translation of the original code, its purpose was to make it easier to see what the original does.

Comment: @eljobso I've added a way to print out only what is actually in the array. Was that what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you intended `ptr` to iterate through the items in the `words` array, but in fact it is actually iterating through the characters of "`word1`".  To iterate through the `words` array, while pretending to not know the number of items to iterate through, then change the while condition as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *words[] = {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
    char numWords = sizeof(words) / sizeof( words[0]);
    int i = 0;

    while(i < numWords)
    {
        printf("%s", *(words+i));

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to use ptr to iterate through the items of the words array, then change the words array and the while condition as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *words[] = {"word1", "word2", "word3", NULL};
    char *ptr[] = words;
    int i = 0;

    while(ptr[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", *(words+i));

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```